# How do I pass form variables from views to controllers in Rails 4?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, view, parameter-passing

I'm trying to accept telephone numbers in a simple form and I can't seem to get it to pass the variable through to the controller.  The code I have so far is:

view on /users/new.erb:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= field_set_tag do %>

    <p><%= f.label :phone %><br>

       <%= f.text_field :phone%>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

and in the controller I have:

```
def new
   @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:new])
  phone = @user.phone
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code. When you write:

```
<%= form_for @user %>
```

All the form fields are sent to the controller in the form of a hash with "user" as the root. Just like

```
{"user": {"phone": "ENTERED PHONE NUMBER"}}
```

To access these fields in the controller you need to use the following method:

```
@phone_number = params[:user][:phone]
```

**One More Important Thing**

For security purposes rails does uses Strong Parameters. It means that you can't use the form parameters directly in Active Model for mass assignment like this:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

You need to permit all the fields explicitly for mass assignment. This can be achieved as follows.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params_user)
  @user.save
end

private 
def params_user
  params.require(:user).permit(:phone)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`params[:new]` just passes the parameter `:new` to your `@user` object, but there is no `params[:new]` parameter because it is not defined in your form. `params[:phone]` should be passed to '@user' just params if you want all available params that were submitted.

Try

```
@user = User.new(params) #instead of @user = User.new(params[:new])

@user.phone
```